# Convert escaped less than sign inside pre tags

Tags: laravel, htmlpurifier, parsedown

I'm using HTMLPurifier to escape characters within my site. Effectively turning all `<` and `>` into `&gt;` and `&lt` as it should. I also want to display code within the site, but when placing code onto the site using `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`, instead of rendering the `&gt;` and `&lt` symbols as `<` and `>` they stay displaying as their encoded `&gt;`.

*I know that the* `<pre>` *tag is meant to show pre-formatted text*

How would I safely convert these symbols (`&gt;` & `&lt;`), only when wrapped in a `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` tags to render as (`<` & `>`) using JS/JQuery?

`<php 'default' => 'local'` converts into `&lt;php 'default' =&gt; 'local'`

NOTE: This doesn't happen when rendering HTML tags. I believe it is something that is caused by HTMLPurifier.

HTML renders correctly as

```
    <div>
      ...Some code here...
    </div>
```

### UPDATE #1:

I'm using Markdown on the site and my HTMLPurifier config is as follows:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Ok, glad you are here
     * first we get a config instance, and set the settings
     * $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
     * $config->set('Core.Encoding', $this->config->get('purifier.encoding'));
     * $config->set('Cache.SerializerPath', $this->config->get('purifier.cachePath'));
     * if ( ! $this->config->get('purifier.finalize')) {
     *     $config->autoFinalize = false;
     * }
     * $config->loadArray($this->getConfig());
     *
     * You must NOT delete the default settings
     * anything in settings should be compacted with params that needed to instance HTMLPurifier_Config.
     *
     * @link http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html
     */

    return [
        'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
        'finalize'      => true,
        'cachePath'     => storage_path('app/purifier'),
        'cacheFileMode' => 0755,
        'settings'      => [
            'default' => [
                'HTML.Doctype'             => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
                'HTML.Allowed'             => 'blockquote,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,div[class],b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
                'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
                'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
                'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
            ],
            'test'    => [
                'Attr.EnableID' => true
            ],
            "youtube" => [
                "HTML.SafeIframe"      => 'true',
                "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
            ],
        ],

    ];

This is the method I'm using to call the Purifier

    public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //Validate the data
            $this->validate($request, array(
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
                'category_id' =>'required|integer',
                'body' => 'required'
            ));
            //Store in the database
            $post = new Post;

            $post->title = $request->title;
            $post->slug = $request->slug;
            $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
            $post->body = Purifier::clean($request->body, "youtube");

            $post->save();

            $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

            Session::flash('success', 'AWESOMESAUCE! Your post was saved successfully!');

            //redirect to another page
            return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);

        }
```

### UPDATE #2 (02/19/19)

The issue caused me to search the previous code. The issue came from the Markdown parser, which is *Parsedown* and not the Purifier. Purifier was working properly. I've added the Markdown configuration and usage code below:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of Laravel Markdown.
 *
 * (c) Graham Campbell <graham@alt-three.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable View Integration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if the view integration is enabled so you can write
    | markdown views and have them rendered as html. The following extensions
    | are currently supported: ".md", ".md.php", and ".md.blade.php". You may
    | disable this integration if it is conflicting with another package.
    |
    | Default: true
    |
    */

    'views' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | CommonMark Extenstions
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies what extensions will be automatically enabled.
    | Simply provide your extension class names here.
    |
    | Default: []
    |
    */

    'extensions' => [],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Renderer Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies an array of options for rendering HTML.
    |
    | Default: [
    |              'block_separator' => "\n",
    |              'inner_separator' => "\n",
    |              'soft_break'      => "\n",
    |          ]
    |
    */

    'renderer' => [
        'block_separator' => "\n",
        'inner_separator' => "\n",
        'soft_break'      => "\n",
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable Em Tag Parsing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if `<em>` parsing is enabled.
    |
    | Default: true
    |
    */

    'enable_em' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable Strong Tag Parsing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if `<strong>` parsing is enabled.
    |
    | Default: true
    |
    */

    'enable_strong' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable Asterisk Parsing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if `*` should be parsed for emphasis.
    |
    | Default: true
    |
    */

    'use_asterisk' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable Underscore Parsing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if `_` should be parsed for emphasis.
    |
    | Default: true
    |
    */

    'use_underscore' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Safe Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option specifies if raw HTML is rendered in the document. Setting
    | this to true will not render HTML, and false will.
    |
    | Default: false
    |
    */

    'safe' => true,

];
```

Usage:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/img/' . $post->image) }}" alt="{{ $post->alt }}" />
    {!! Markdown::parse($post->body) !!}
    <hr />
```

Comment: Please add more and real code to your example to give you a better solution to your question

Comment: Can you tell us (1) what context these are rendered in (are you using a WYSIWYG anywhere, for example)? and (2) what the pre-purified and post-purified `source code` looks like? and (3) how you are calling HTML Purifier (its configuration, especially)?

Comment: Thank you, I've added the configuration code and how I'm calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars() function to archieve this, htmlspecialchars() function Convert the predefined characters "<" (less than) and ">" (greater than) to HTML entities:

```
<?php
$str = "This is some <b>bold</b> text.";
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
?>
```

this will print:

```
This is some &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is an issue with HTMLPurifier during more investigation to answer your comment. I came across that the problem doesn't happen when certain HTML elements are entered.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue adding, in the Purifier configuration, to the **HTML.Allowed** property:

```
pre[class],code
```

Then I clean the code using just:

```
$post->body = clean($request->body, "youtube");
```

If you are using TinyMCE as editor you have also to add the to the property **extended_valid_elements**:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target],pre[class],code',
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The question was updated. I further searched and found that the Purifier was doing it's job correctly, but my Markdown Parser was causing this issue. I've updated the question with the details.